# Android's default su

Tags: android, su

Root Checker fails on Android's default `su` (built from AOSP), but in `adb shell` it works fine. It seems this `su` program doesn't provide root access to the Android framework. But I don't quite know the details. Is there anyone who can explain it? Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @NikolayElenkov Why does this `su` work for adb but not for the framework

Comment: It fails because Android's default su is not intended to be usable by unprivileged users.  The only reason it is working from the adb shell is that on an engineering build adb shell is typically already root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Chris pointed out the reason in his comment. `su` works on an engineering build, but not on a factory ROM. It looks like this has something to do with build flags.

Answer (score 0):

Root Checker usually gives you the detailed explanation, why it thinks something is wrong. Please refer to the Root Checker output or copy/paste it to your question if you need further clarification.

Answer (score 0):

How did you install the `su` program? To actually be useful it needs to have the `setuid` flag set. If you didn't set it, `su` won't work properly. Root Checker and similar tools likely check for the flag, so that is why it fails. Runs `ls -l /path/to/su` to verify flags and permissions.